# Has anyone seen details on Apple's SharePlay working with React Native?

Tags: react-native, ios15

I am just wondering if there is a plugin or way to integrate the [Apple Shareplay functionality](https://developer.apple.com/shareplay/) from iOS 15 into react native without writing in Swift at this time.

Thanks!